# How to prevent updates in TRANSPOSE range from messing up header order on other sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When using `TRANSPOSE` to populate headers on ***sheet2*** from a column on ***sheet1***, how can you prevent issues with the data in ***sheet2*** becoming out of sync with the header when there are updates to ***sheet1***.

I couldn't think of any elegant solution, and would like to still have the ability to add data in ***sheet2*** directly, as well as the ability to update information on ***sheet1***.

I considered pasting with transpose into ***sheet2*** so it was static, but then I have lost any updates from ***sheet1*** and I feel it is going to be harder to identify what changes need to be made as well.

Here is an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ayRDJ3z7od6kuigEew8n-ar7hH4eE-KMVCyznSwsZZI/edit?usp=sharing).

In this sheet I populated it with breweries from Michigan.
Then I populated ***sheet2*** with the transpose headers and styles of beer.
Then I put checks at random for each.

Then I created a cached copy with the static ***sheet2*** data before removing all the closed Michigan breweries.

You can see the information on ***sheet2*** becomes invalid.

I wish to prevent this.

I can't see a way around this through formulas alone. I thought there may be a script that could copy the columns over like Transpose but also move the data in ***sheet2*** around when column headers move, disappear or are added.

Comment: What do you mean by "using TRANSPOSE"? Are question about the built-in transpose function? Why is [tag:google-apps-script] included? Did you tried write a script and it failed? If the last is true see [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I failed to provide a demo. I was referring to the built in transpose option but included the google-apps-script because there were a few options I have considered that were scripts. Perhaps I should have left it off.  I will follow up with an example sheet.

Comment: Updated with the spreadsheet and steps I took to break it. You can also look at the revision history, probably. I updated the permissions for it to allow comments.

Comment: If the question doesn't include anything directly related to a tag, that tag  should not be included.

Comment: Fair enough. I shared my thoughts on how it could be solved. But I still don't know how exactly and hoped there was a concept that could tie this all together. I imagine maybe an ID column in ***sheet1*** would be required.

Comment: If the headers and row are unique it's not necessary the use of an ID. Bear in mind that spreadsheets are best suited to do calculations not to be used to handle complex databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108228/discussion-between-ehlovader-and-ruben).

Answer (score 1):

What your are trying to do is to use a crosstab in a spreadsheet to manage user input and to store data . As you already figured out this could cause troubles when the "headers" are changed in the source.

A better approach is to use simple tables to store data. In the example provided, the solution is to add a column for each kind of beers to the **Sheet1** to store the "checks".

Side note: As there are many breweries in Michigan your spreadsheet usability of the input/data storage sheet could be improved by using filters and freezing one or two rows and columns.

Then to create the crosstab report use  the following formulas in a new sheet:

Cell B1 : Column Headers

```
=transpose(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26)
```

Cell A2 : Row Headers

```
=transpose(Sheet1!$C$1:$H$1)
```

CELL B2 : cross tabbed values

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(B1:Z1,Sheet1!$A$2:$H$26,Match(A2:A7,Sheet1!$C$1:$H$1,0)+2,0))
```

As cell B2 includes an array formula, if you edit any of the required cells to display the result, you will get an error like the following

> **Error**
>   Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in reference.

So this will let you remember that you should edit the data at the source, in the example provided it's the **Sheet1**.

Comment: Thanks Rubén, this was the first thought I had. I also felt that input for the data that might populate the rows could be entered through a form to make it easier. But I really hoped to have minimal changes to the workflow of those using the spreadsheet.

Comment: To the point of those improvements... This was just a quick and dirty example. The real use case is an internal sheet used initially for meeting times across the business and what was going to go on sheet two were the people on my team who attended a meeting that week. This will run for a few weeks.